# Finding the points on a perimeter to denote a boundary/shape

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a simple 2D grid with the format of `myGrid[x,y]`

I am trying to find a way to find the perimeter around a selection of grids so i then have a shape for the selection.

This is an example of what i mean:

[image]

The idea here is to find all the relevant "corners" aka the red points in the image on the perimeter into a list so i can then create a 2D mesh from it. But i don't know the easiest way to do this. I was wondering if there is a simple logic to do this ?

Comment: So.. you have information about gray cells, right? I mean you know the coordinates of these cells. Am I correct?

Comment: Yeah i have their `position` and the `zone` they belong to aka the grey zone for these tiles, tiles can be adjacent to other zone colours. Black is undefined tiles essentially null in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your shape is whole and solid, here are some ideas.
First of all, you can of course limit the searching area by min/max coordinates:
[image]

Then I'd find all the outer and inner corners by looping through the grid cells with the following criterias:

- Outer corner has at least two null diagonal adjacent cells.
- Inner corner has only one adjacent cell.

[image]

Then you can just iterate through the found corners in a 2-levels loop to find a bounding route around the shape:
[image]

That's not the most effective algorithm, but it's pretty simple to implement.

**Here's an alternative solution:**

1. Find the first corner cell by the criteria above.
2. Move along the shape side until you reach the next corner. Use the fact the simple side cell has two adjacent null cells and two adjacent not null cells.
3. Repeat #2 until you reach the corner found at #1.

Comment: Slight issue with the inner corner, the inner corner point is the tile location of the grey tile to it's right. Which means it has 2 null cells but this isn't always the case of course. Image example shows what i mean: 

http://i.imgur.com/3mlxWqB.jpg

The left corner denotes each tile so it gets confusing that some corners are actually part of a null tile which isn't part of the zone (or it could be part of another zone). If that makes sense?

Comment: The code will find the cell right diagonal to the inner corner, not the one you marked. As the inner corner criteria is "it has one and only one null (or another shape) cell around".

Comment: @Sir sorry, can't post images from the phone. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: I think you are confusing the issue that the view angle is rotated 45 degrees. I probably should have rotated the camera to be face on more. Lets say a corner has 2 diagonals that are not part of the zone: http://i.imgur.com/1tbYsTx.jpg the actual corner position is kinda confusing to find, the code becomes super long in terms of all the logic involved.